# Is it possible to reconnect a calendar to an active mailbox in exchange online?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

Since last accessing the mailbox (16th january), a user noticed his calendar ("agenda" because it is in dutch) can now be "removed" (which you cannot do with the main calendar), and has a new default calendar ("calendar").

Because all the appointments (also recurrent) still are present in the "agenda", we'd like to reconnect this as the main calendar.

1. What could have triggered the creation of a new, not correctly localized calendar?
2. Is there a way we can put the "agenda" back as primary calendar en remove the newly generated "calendar"?

Comment: Number 2 is kind of taken care of, I'm still puzzled as how nr.1 could happen...

Answer (score 0):

1. You could use mailbox audit log to check if there is any delegate create the new one and use admin audit log to check if administrator change some configuration for this mailbox.
2. Based on my knowledge, there is no way to change the primary calendar. Did you check the calendar via OWA?
   The quick way is to export the old calendar data into new calendar.

Comment: I had done that (2.) already, I'm struggling with this bug now: on other devices (than the device I imported), all recurrent meetings are double. Any idea how this could happen?